"manually" weighted regression
I have a dataset with weighted observations. I'm trying to find a way to perform a weighted regression without having to specify weights. That is, I want to find transformations of the variables $X$ and $Y$ (denoted $\tilde{X}$ and $\ddot{Y}$), such that when perform an OLS estimation of $\ddot{Y}$ on $\tilde{X}$, I actually perform a weighted regression of $Y$ on $X$ using weights $W$.
If $W$ is a diagonal matrix, then the OLS coefficients can be obtained as:
$$
\hat{\beta}_{wols} = (X'WX)^{-1} X'WY.
$$
That means that I can transform $X$ and $Y$ with the square root of $W$:
$$
\ddot{Y} = \sqrt{W}Y\\
\tilde{X} = \sqrt{W}X.
$$
Notice that this a regression without intercept of $\ddot{Y}$ on the squared root-weighted variables $X$, and a vector of the those squared root weights.
The problem I have is that the model statistics (R-squared, in particular) are different from the regular weighted regression.
Does anyone know of another transformation such that when I compute the unweighted OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}_{ols}$ on the transformed variables I get back $\hat{\beta}_{wols}$ and correspondent model statistics?
The use case I have is that I want to "hack" an estimation program that does not support weights to perform a weighted regression.

Is the intercept in $X$? Do you multiply the intercept by $\sqrt{W}$?

Yes, the intercept is in $X$. If you multiply the intercept in $X$ by $sqrt(W)$ you end up with a column of weights in $\tilde{X}$ and no intercept.

If you use R (but then why don't just do WLS?) lm(Y ~ 0 + Intercept + X, weights = W^2) and lm(WY ~ 0 + WIntercept + WX) should give identical results. Intercept is a vector of 1s.

Yes, that would give me what I need in terms of coefficients and standard errors. However, I need to use it on a software that does not allow for weights, but makes use of R-squared.

Depending on what the limitation of your software are, you can compute the R-squared explicitly when you have the $\hat{\beta}_{wls}$. (The sums of squares are also weighted in WLS).

Ah true! I didn't think about that. However, the software uses R-squared in a single pass, so I don't have a chance to "fix" it. Hence my ask for a transform of the data.

The transformation, multiplying by sqrt(w), is correct. The challenge -- at least in R -- is that the transformed OLS has no "true intercept" and instead has the "weighted intercept", which for all intents and purposes looks like a predictor. And internally R computes R-square differently for models with and without intercept. So in R it's not possible in a single pass. I guess in your software too?

Yes, that's what I figure. But perhaps there is a way. Maybe setting up the problem as constrained optimization, then obtaining closed form expressions that hint to some transform of the data?

I don't think so. The optimization problem (to minimize the weighted residual sum of squares WSS = sum(w*e^2))) is solved correctly. Adding constraints would only give you a solution to a different problem. R-squared is just a summary of the correct solution computed incorrectly because of the hack.

TL;DR The coefficient of determination, R-squared, is calculated differently for a regression with and without an intercept: Removal of statistically significant intercept term increases 2
in linear model. So while you can solve for the weighted regression parameters using OLS on the transformed data, ($\sqrt w\times x$, $\sqrt w\times y$), you don't get the correct R-squared if the "original" weighted regression has an intercept but the software uses the without-intercept formula for R-squared on the "transformed" linear regression. Instead you can calculate the weighted R-squared explicitly.
The objective of ordinary least squares (OLS) is to minimize the residual sum of squares $\text{RSS} = \sum_i e_i^2$. The objective of weighted least squares (WLS) is to minimize the weighted residual sum of squares $\text{WSS} = \sum_i w_ie_i^2$.
Up to proper math notation, minimizing WSS is equivalent to minimizing
$$
\sum_i{\left(\sqrt w_i e_i\right)^2} = \sum_i{\left(\sqrt{w_i}y_i - \sqrt{w_i}x_i \beta\right)^2} = \sum_i {(\tilde y - \tilde x \beta)^2}
$$
This is the OLS objective given the transformed data $(\tilde x, \tilde y) = (\sqrt{w}\times x, \sqrt{w}\times y)$. As stated in the question, we can solve a WLS problem with OLS by transforming the model matrix $x$ and the response $y$ appropriately.
About the math notation: Here $w$ is a diagonal matrix of weights, the response $y$ is a column vector, the design matrix $x$ is a matrix with a column of 1s for the intercept, and $\beta$ is a column vector of model coefficients.
So we can obtain the WLS solution by using OLS on the transformed data. What about the R-squared?
The R-squared won't be computed correctly if the weighted regression has an intercept term. That's because we would use the with-intercept formula for R-squared if we were doing WLS but the transformed OLS model doesn't have an intercept term: by construction the column of 1s in $x$ is transformed into a column of weights $\sqrt{w}$ in $\tilde{x} = \sqrt{w}\times x$. So by default the software would use the without-intercept formula — unless it's possible to override the default. (That's what happens in R at least; I don't know the details of how the OP's software works.)
Here's how to do the calculation in R. See also How does R compute r.squared for weighted least squares? and @JulienMassardier's answer to Is a weighted 2 in robust linear model meaningful for goodness of fit analysis?.
set.seed(1234)

n <- 12 # number of observations
x <- rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = 3) # one or more predictors
y <- 3 + 0.5 * x + rnorm(n) # response
w <- rexp(n, 1) # weights

x <- cbind(1, x) # design matrix with intercept

# WLS
# wls.fit <- lm.wfit(x, y, w)
wls.fit <- lm(y ~ x, weights = w)

# Transformed OLS
x_tilde <- diag(sqrt(w)) %*% x
y_tilde <- diag(sqrt(w)) %*% y
ols.fit <- lm.fit(x_tilde, y_tilde)

weighted.r.squared <- function(ols.fit, weights, wls.intercept = TRUE) {
  f <- ols.fit$fitted.values / sqrt(weights)
  r <- ols.fit$residuals / sqrt(weights)
  y <- f + r # reconstructed response

  # We need to be careful about the intercept.
  # While transformed linear regression doesn't have an intercept,
  # what matters is whether the weighted regression has an intercept or not.

  if (wls.intercept) {
    m <- weighted.mean(y, weights)
  } else {
    m <- 0
  }

  tss <- sum(weights * (y - m)^2)
  mss <- sum(weights * (f - m)^2)
  rss <- sum(weights * r^2)

  # Two ways to compute R-squared.
  # r.squared <- mss / (mss + rss)
  r.squared <- 1 - rss / tss
  r.squared
}

# The weighted R-squared we want to obtain with OLS
summary(wls.fit)$r.squared
#> [1] 0.4585256
weighted.r.squared(ols.fit, w, wls.intercept = FALSE) # incorrect R-squared
#> [1] 0.9696842
weighted.r.squared(ols.fit, w, wls.intercept = TRUE) # correct R-squared
#> [1] 0.4585256


You forgot the weights in the RHS of your equations.

Hello @whuber. Thank you for help me fix a mistake in my answer. It took me a while to figure what you might mean. Is it that wls$residuals and ols_tilde$residuals are not the same? That's why I divide by sqrt(weights) in the weighted.r.squared function. So to summarise: in the equations for RSS and WSS it's not clear that these are not the same e_is? With that math I was trying to argue that it's possible to solve for $\hat{\beta}_{\text{WLS}}$ with OLS on the transformed data.

Not sure how to say it correctly without making it too complex; obviously I'm not great at math. I think $\min(\tilde{y}-\tilde{x}\beta)^2$ gives the correct $\hat{\beta}$ but it doesn't mean that it reproduces the WLS fit in all the details. The "hack" gives us all the ingredients (we really need only $x$, $y$, $w$ and $\hat{\beta}$) to calculate everything in summary(wls.fit) by hand.

I am sorry: in reading this on the phone I missed the tildes that incorporate the weights.
